# R - Subsetting in dredge (MuMin) – only include interaction with b if also an interaction with a

Tags: r, variables, subset, interaction, mumin

I am wanting to use dredge::MuMIn to explore my data. I only want to include an interaction between `I(GISalt^2)` and one of the other environmental variables if there is also an interaction between the variable and `GISalt`.

e.g. I would like to keep:

```
(GISalt * Forest) AND (I(GISalt^2) * Forest)
mod1 <- glm(MLE2017 ~ MLE200405 + (GISalt * Forest) + Scrub + I(GISalt^2) * Forest)
```

and

```
(GISalt * Forest) but NOT I(GISalt^2) * Forest)
mod2 <- glm(MLE2017 ~ MLE200405 + (GISalt * Forest) + Scrub)
```

and to exclude:

I(GISalt^2) * Forest) but NOT GISalt * Forest)
   mod3 <- glm(MLE2017 ~ MLE200405 + Scrub + I(GISalt^2) * Forest)

global model containing all variables for `dredge()`

```
globmod <- glm(MLE2017 ~ MLE200405 + GISalt * Forest + GISalt * Scrub 
    + GISalt * Meadow + GISalt * RiverLgthm + GISalt * DailySunHrs  + 
    I(GISalt^2) * Forest + I(GISalt^2) * Scrub + I(GISalt^2) * Meadow +
    I(GISalt^2) * RiverLgthm + I(GISalt^2) * DailySunHrs, 
    data = GLMdata, family = x.quasipoisson(link = "log"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an expression of form `dc(I(A^2):B, A:B)` or, more explicitly `!{I(A^2):B} || {A:B}`, i.e. "either no *A^2 * B*, or *A * B*" or  (note that `A*B` in an R formula is a shorthand for `A+B+A:B`, where `A:B` is the actual interaction term). There is no out-of-box way in `dredge` to expand B to "any other variable", but you can generate a suitable expression for a list of terms.

If the general expression is `!{I(A^2):VARIABLE} || {A:VARIABLE}`, you can use `substitute` to well, substitute the name `VARIABLE` with an actual variable name.

```
substitute((!{I(A^2):VARIABLE} || {A:VARIABLE}), list(VARIABLE = as.name("B")))
```

yields `!{I(A^2):B} || {A:B}`. Create such expression for each of "the other variables" using `&&` operator.
Wrapping all that in a function:

```
makeRule <- function(...) {
    exprList <- lapply(sys.call()[-1], function(x) substitute((! {I(A^2):VAR} || {A:VAR}), list(VAR = x)))
    rval <- exprList[[1]]
    for(x in exprList[-1]) rval <- call("&&", rval, x)
    rval
}
```

then:

```
 subsetExpr <- makeRule(B,C,D,E)

 dredge(model, subset = subsetExpr)
```