# How to always keep two variables to interact with other variables simultaneously in model selection using dredge() in R?

Tags: r, mumin

The title may not be very explicit, I will use code to illustrate.
My actual data got a four-way interaction, here I simplified it to three-way:

```
colnames(iris) <- c("y", "a", "b", "c")

m1 <- lm(y ~ a * b * (sin(c) + cos(c)),
         na.action = "na.fail", data = iris)
```

Which is equally:

`a + b + sin(c) + cos(c) + a:b + a:sin(c) + a:cos(c) + b:sin(c) + b:cos(c) + a:b:sin(c) + a:b:cos(c)`

I want `sin(c)` and `cos(c)` to present or absent as an entirety in the model selection, so do the `a:sin(c)` and `a:cos(c)`, `b:sin(c)` and `b:cos(c)`, `a:b:sin(c)` and `a:b:cos(c)`.

Currently I can do it by using a complex subsetting logic in `dredge()`:

```
m1_d <- MuMIn::dredge(m1, trace = 2, subset = 
                 (`sin(c)` & `cos(c)` & 
                    `a:sin(c)` & `a:cos(c)` &
                    `b:sin(c)` & `b:cos(c)` &
                    `a:b:sin(c)` & `a:b:cos(c)`) | 
                 
                 (`sin(c)` & `cos(c)` & 
                    `a:sin(c)` & `a:cos(c)` &
                    `b:sin(c)` & `b:cos(c)` &
                    !`a:b:sin(c)` & !`a:b:cos(c)`) | 
                 
                 (`sin(c)` & `cos(c)` & 
                    `a:sin(c)` & `a:cos(c)` &
                    !`b:sin(c)` & !`b:cos(c)`) | 
                 
                 (`sin(c)` & `cos(c)` & 
                    !`a:sin(c)` & !`a:cos(c)` &
                    `b:sin(c)` & `b:cos(c)`) |
                 
                 (`sin(c)` & `cos(c)` & 
                    !`a:sin(c)` & !`a:cos(c)` &
                    !`b:sin(c)` & !`b:cos(c)`) |
                 
                 (!`sin(c)` & !`cos(c)` &
                    `a:sin(c)` & `a:cos(c)` &
                    `b:sin(c)` & `b:cos(c)`) | 
                 
                 (!`sin(c)` & !`cos(c)` &
                    `a:sin(c)` & `a:cos(c)` &
                    !`b:sin(c)` & !`b:cos(c)`) | 
                 
                 (!`sin(c)` & !`cos(c)` &
                    !`a:sin(c)` & !`a:cos(c)` &
                    `b:sin(c)` & `b:cos(c)`) |
                 
                 (!`sin(c)` & !`cos(c)` &
                    !`a:sin(c)` & !`a:cos(c)` &
                    !`b:sin(c)` & !`b:cos(c)`))
```

But this eventually became a thousand line of code with a four-way interaction.

I checked similar questions using `dredge()`, but they were not helpful to my case.

[Subsetting in dredge (MuMIn) - must include interaction if main effects are present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247263/subsetting-in-dredge-mumin-must-include-interaction-if-main-effects-are-pres)
[R - Subsetting in dredge (MuMin) – only include interaction with b if also an interaction with a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167595/r-subsetting-in-dredge-mumin-only-include-interaction-with-b-if-also-an-in)

I think there should be a more efficient way to do this?